# Importing database SQL syntax error in Prestashop

Tags: mysql, sql, database, prestashop, ovh

I'm developing a simple eshop to a French client (I'm Portuguese) at PRESTASHOP, everything went marvellous but we faced some issues when configuring the Payment System ATOS. We were using VIADUC.fr services, and due to those issues we have recently changed to OVH.

**Problem:** OVH offers a database, and now when I'm trying to import my database I have the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near './PaxHeaders.7074

OVH help me to find what the issue was, but can't help solve it because this "goes out of their scope", and I have really tiny experience with this.

The eshop has been delayed because of this matter and i can't delay it much longer.

Comment: A data load that triggers a SQL syntax error is clearly an application error. Do you have the resources and will to fix the codebase? (I'm assuming that Prestashop has an import feature you are using, please correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: Same MySQL versions?

Comment: Martina could you please add the lines surrounding this code `PaxHeaders. 7074` in your sql file?

Comment: Ok so your trying to upload a `tar.gz` file that might be corrupted. Could you untar it before uploading it to ovh? If the file is too large you can log into your site with ssh on command line and import it with `mysql` command.

Comment: Can you make sure the MySQL versions are compatible ?

Comment: How are you importing the database? What tool/application are you using for this? Is your database a standard SQL file?